# Basic use of derivative with cool package fails with "Missing \endcsname inserted"

Tags: math-mode

In exploring options for typesetting derivatives I came across [the `cool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cool). But a basic example from Page 22 of the [Content Oriented LaTeX documentation (October 7, 2006)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cool/Content_LaTeX_Package_Demo.pdf) seems to result in the error:

```
 Missing \endcsname inserted.
  <to be read again> 
                \toks@
```

Uncommenting the line in the MWE below yields the above error.  As is, the MWE produces:

[image]

### References:

- [Can I have a flexible partial derivative macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/can-i-have-a-flexible-partial-derivative-macro)
  I would prefer to use one of the solutions mentioned here as they do not require another package, but the syntax proposed here is different that the `cool` package. This is problematic in that if I later need the flexibility provided by the the `cool` package will not be as easy to switch.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cool}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \D[1]{f}{x,y,z} &= \cdots\\
    %\D[2,n,3]{f}{x,y,z} &= x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't help you. But I want to say that I think it's easier to create an own command based on LaTeX3.

Comment: Also note that according to [ISO 31/XI](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) the differential operator should be upright.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: That would be acceptable, but would prefer that they use a similar syntax as the `cool` package in case I need to switch at some later date.  The question I linked to provides some nice options, but with a different syntax.

Comment: @Waldheri: Besides the minor issue like not working :-), that is one of the things I don't like about the `cool` package. But, I assume that there is probably a way to patch that as well.

Comment: Copying one of the doc examples produces errors. I don't have here older TeX Live versions to test, but the error is the same with TeX Live 2010.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in the `cool` package v1.35 (2006/12/29). Lines 2056 to 2063 read

```
\whiledo{ \boolean{COOL@isint} \AND
\NOT \value{COOL@multideriv}>\value{COOL@ct}  }%
{%
\def\COOL@tempd%
{\csname COOL@deriv@powers@\roman{COOL@multideriv}\endcsname}%
\isint{\COOL@tempd}{COOL@isint}%
\stepcounter{COOL@multideriv}%
}
```

The `\def` (line 2059) must be an `\edef`. After changing it (in a local copy, of course) the MWE ran without errors.

BTW: the style of the “d” can be changed through:

```
\Style{DSymb={\mathrm d}}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Ages ago (I think after reading the question that Peter links to), I tried the `cool` package, ran into a problem, and gave up.  Looking at my test file, I appear to have gotten stuck with commands of the form `\COOL@deriv@powers@ii` not being defined which looks extremely like what this fixes.  Looks like `cool` might just be cool again.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a contact address to send a bug report to :(

Comment: @cgnieder: Google led me to the [author's website](http://nsetzer.com/contact.shtml), where he explains how to write his email address.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Curious... I was sure I tried google, too. Anyway, thanks! I'll contact him.

Comment: @cgnieder: I'm sure you did, too.  I used keywords `n setzer cool latex` and that led me to [nsetzer.com](http://www.nsetzer.com/).  I'm not sure how active he is...the site has not been updated in a while.  If he's not responsive I believe there is a CTAN process for taking over maintenance.

Comment: BTW: I contacted the author a while ago and he came back to me hoping to update the package soon.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following macro to set multiple partial derivatives:

```
\newcommand*\mdiff[3]{\frac{\partial^{#2}{#1}}{\pABLN{#3}}}
\newcounter{pABLCounter}
\def\pABLN#1{\setcounter{pABLCounter}{1}\xpABLN#1;pABLEnde;}
\def\pABLEnde{pABLEnde}
\def\xpABLN#1;{\def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\pABLEnde
  \else 
    \stepcounter{pABLCounter}
    \ifodd \value{pABLCounter} 
      \if1#1\,\else {{}^{#1}\,}\fi%
      \else{\partial{#1}}% 
    \fi %
    \expandafter\xpABLN
  \fi  
}
```

to set in your case:

```
\mdiff{f}{3}{x;1;y;1;z;1}
```

other possibilities are:

```
\mdiff{f}{5}{x;1;z;4}
```

giving `\frac{\partial^5f}{\partial x\partial z^4}`.

If you really want `d` instead of `\partial` just replace it in the code.

Comment: Can you not improve you macro to require only 2 argument? The second argument can be computed from the third 3. This would surely make it less error prone.

Comment: @Walter but then I coudn't write things like `\mdiff{f}{m+n}{x;m;y;n}`