# cool package derivative and eulervm \mathbold fails with 'Missing control sequence inserted.'

Tags: fonts, math-mode, macros

Compiling

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cool}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}

$\D{a}{T}$
$\pderiv{a}{T}$

$\mathbold{T}$

$\D{a}{\mathbold{T}}$
$\pderiv{a}{\mathbold{T}}$

\end{document}
```

works until the derivatives are evaluated for bold euler letters. It fails with

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
              \inaccessible 
l.13     $\D{a}{\mathbold{T}}
                         $
```

Perhaps this is related to [Basic use of derivative with cool package fails with “Missing \endcsname inserted”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54425/basic-use-of-derivative-with-cool-package-fails-with-missing-endcsname-inserte) but the fix proposed there does not work.

Comment: The package `cool` uses many `\edef` commands and most of them should be `\protected@edef`.

Comment: Is it possible to inform the maintainer of this issue? The last version seems to be of 2006.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is usually a sign of a fragile command in a moving argument, so a guess of making something robust seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cool}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\let\oldmb\mathbold
\protected\def\mathbold{\oldmb}
\begin{document}

$\D{a}{T}$
$\pderiv{a}{T}$

$\mathbold{T}$

$\D{a}{\mathbold{T}}$
$\pderiv{a}{\mathbold{T}}$

\end{document}
```

This method also fixes `Undefined control sequence` and `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]` errors that occur when using cool commands such as `\D` or `\pderiv` with denominator arguments containing math accents like `\tilde` and `\dot`.

Comment: Greate, thanks, I didn't knew about the existence of fragile commands, but protecting them seems to work! :)