# Help recalling a package which automatically calculates derivative orders

Tags: symbols, packages, calculations, stacking-symbols

I distinctly recall stumbling upon a package which typeset derivatives nicely, and moreover automatically calculated some of the indices involved in partial differentiation. Unfortunately, I can't remember at all what this package is called.

Does anyone remember/know such a package?

Comment: The `cool` package maybe? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54425/

Comment: @clemens not it :\

Comment: `esdiff`, `bropd`,  and `physics` are other packages I found in a quick search http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=derivative*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have been thinking of [diffcoeff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff).

Answer (score 2):

Another similar package to write derivatives, among those that have been shown, there is also the [`derivative`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.pdf) package where it is possible to write: ordinary, partial, functional, material derivative, average rate of change and Jacobian.
Here there is a small example with a screenshot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\[\odv{f(x)}{x}_{a}^{b}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]